# Calculating the width of the YOLO bounding box in pixels

Tags: image, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to find the width of the bounding box of the output image in pixels:

[image]

[In this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/), it says YOLO v3 extracts coordinates and dimensions of the bounding box (line 82). YOLO returns bounding box coordinates in the form:

```
(centerX, centerY, width, and height)
```

Are these coordinates, width and height, real pixel values? Or do they perform scaling on them? 
Can I print out the value of width and consider it as a real pixel value for the width of the aforementioned box?

Please note that my question is about YOLO v3.

Comment: check [pybboxes](https://github.com/devrimcavusoglu/pybboxes).

Answer (score 1):

Those are what are called normalized coordinates. To get the width in pixels you would need to multiply by the width of the images. For example if your image 640x480 than multiple the width values outputted by Yolo by the width of the image.

If the numbers in your screenshot are the width:

Dog width = .98 * 640 = 627 px
Cat width = .88 * 563 = 563 px

Comment: Sorry I did not get that how do you mean? what is the 563 in that calculation? what are 0.88 and 0.98?

Comment: In the picture you provided above. It days dog = 98% and cat ==88%. I thought was the width.

Take the width from the output (centerX, centerY, width, and height), multiply by the width of the pixels of the image and you have the width of the bounding box in pixels.