# Calculating height and width of a bounding box in Yolov5

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

Currently I am working with Yolov5 and I have done training and validation on custom dataset and the results are quite impressive. Now I want to calculate the height and width of the object(bounding box) and present it on screen just like confidence score. In Yolov5 there's one option to save the cordinates of a bounding box in text file. I have done that but finding it difficult to put those as an output of detection on screen. This might be because of my limited capabilities in python. I request you all, if the knowledge allows you so kindly take a look and help me.

Thank you.

```
import argparse
import os
import platform
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import torch

FILE = Path(__file__).resolve()
ROOT = FILE.parents[0]  # YOLOv5 root directory
if str(ROOT) not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT))  # add ROOT to PATH
ROOT = Path(os.path.relpath(ROOT, Path.cwd()))  # relative

from models.common import DetectMultiBackend
from utils.dataloaders import IMG_FORMATS, VID_FORMATS, LoadImages, LoadScreenshots, LoadStreams
from utils.general import (LOGGER, Profile, check_file, check_img_size, check_imshow, check_requirements, colorstr, cv2,
                           increment_path, non_max_suppression, print_args, scale_boxes, strip_optimizer, xyxy2xywh)
from utils.plots import Annotator, colors, save_one_box
from utils.torch_utils import select_device, smart_inference_mode


@smart_inference_mode()
def run(
        weights=ROOT / 'yolov5s.pt',  # model path or triton URL
        source=ROOT / 'data/images',  # file/dir/URL/glob/screen/0(webcam)
        data=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml',  # dataset.yaml path
        imgsz=(640, 640),  # inference size (height, width)
        conf_thres=0.25,  # confidence threshold
        iou_thres=0.45,  # NMS IOU threshold
        max_det=1000,  # maximum detections per image
        device='',  # cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu
        view_img=False,  # show results
        save_txt=False,  # save results to *.txt
        save_conf=False,  # save confidences in --save-txt labels
        save_crop=False,  # save cropped prediction boxes
        nosave=False,  # do not save images/videos
        classes=None,  # filter by class: --class 0, or --class 0 2 3
        agnostic_nms=False,  # class-agnostic NMS
        augment=False,  # augmented inference
        visualize=False,  # visualize features
        update=False,  # update all models
        project=ROOT / 'runs/detect',  # save results to project/name
        name='exp',  # save results to project/name
        exist_ok=False,  # existing project/name ok, do not increment
        line_thickness=3,  # bounding box thickness (pixels)
        hide_labels=False,  # hide labels
        hide_conf=False,  # hide confidences
        half=False,  # use FP16 half-precision inference
        dnn=False,  # use OpenCV DNN for ONNX inference
        vid_stride=1,  # video frame-rate stride
):
    source = str(source)
    save_img = not nosave and not source.endswith('.txt')  # save inference images
    is_file = Path(source).suffix[1:] in (IMG_FORMATS + VID_FORMATS)
    is_url = source.lower().startswith(('rtsp://', 'rtmp://', 'http://', 'https://'))
    webcam = source.isnumeric() or source.endswith('.txt') or (is_url and not is_file)
    screenshot = source.lower().startswith('screen')
    if is_url and is_file:
        source = check_file(source)  # download

    # Directories
    save_dir = increment_path(Path(project) / name, exist_ok=exist_ok)  # increment run
    (save_dir / 'labels' if save_txt else save_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # make dir

    # Load model
    device = select_device(device)
    model = DetectMultiBackend(weights, device=device, dnn=dnn, data=data, fp16=half)
    stride, names, pt = model.stride, model.names, model.pt
    imgsz = check_img_size(imgsz, s=stride)  # check image size

    # Dataloader
    bs = 1  # batch_size
    if webcam:
        view_img = check_imshow(warn=True)
        dataset = LoadStreams(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt, vid_stride=vid_stride)
        bs = len(dataset)
    elif screenshot:
        dataset = LoadScreenshots(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt)
    else:
        dataset = LoadImages(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt, vid_stride=vid_stride)
    vid_path, vid_writer = [None] * bs, [None] * bs

    # Run inference
    model.warmup(imgsz=(1 if pt or model.triton else bs, 3, *imgsz))  # warmup
    seen, windows, dt = 0, [], (Profile(), Profile(), Profile())
    for path, im, im0s, vid_cap, s in dataset:
        with dt[0]:
            im = torch.from_numpy(im).to(model.device)
            im = im.half() if model.fp16 else im.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
            im /= 255  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
            if len(im.shape) == 3:
                im = im[None]  # expand for batch dim

        # Inference
        with dt[1]:
            visualize = increment_path(save_dir / Path(path).stem, mkdir=True) if visualize else False
            pred = model(im, augment=augment, visualize=visualize)

        # NMS
        with dt[2]:
            pred = non_max_suppression(pred, conf_thres, iou_thres, classes, agnostic_nms, max_det=max_det)

        # Second-stage classifier (optional)
        # pred = utils.general.apply_classifier(pred, classifier_model, im, im0s)

        # Process predictions
        for i, det in enumerate(pred):  # per image
            seen += 1
            if webcam:  # batch_size >= 1
                p, im0, frame = path[i], im0s[i].copy(), dataset.count
                s += f'{i}: '
            else:
                p, im0, frame = path, im0s.copy(), getattr(dataset, 'frame', 0)

            p = Path(p)  # to Path
            save_path = str(save_dir / p.name)  # im.jpg
            txt_path = str(save_dir / 'labels' / p.stem) + ('' if dataset.mode == 'image' else f'_{frame}')  # im.txt
            s += '%gx%g ' % im.shape[2:]  # print string
            gn = torch.tensor(im0.shape)[[1, 0, 1, 0]]  # normalization gain whwh
            imc = im0.copy() if save_crop else im0  # for save_crop
            annotator = Annotator(im0, line_width=line_thickness, example=str(names))
            if len(det):
                # Rescale boxes from img_size to im0 size
                det[:, :4] = scale_boxes(im.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()

                # Print results
                for c in det[:, 5].unique():
                    n = (det[:, 5] == c).sum()  # detections per class
                    s += f"{n} {names[int(c)]}{'s' * (n > 1)}, "  # add to string

                # Write results
                for *xyxy, conf, cls in reversed(det):
                    if save_txt:  # Write to file
                        xywh = (xyxy2xywh(torch.tensor(xyxy).view(1, 4)) / gn).view(-1).tolist()  # normalized xywh
                        line = (cls, *xywh, conf) if save_conf else (cls, *xywh)  # label format
                        with open(f'{txt_path}.txt', 'a') as f:
                            f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip() % line + '\n')

                    if save_img or save_crop or view_img:  # Add bbox to image
                        c = int(cls)  # integer class
                        label = None if hide_labels else (names[c] if hide_conf else f'{names[c]} {conf:.2f}')
                        annotator.box_label(xyxy, label, color=colors(c, True))
                    if save_crop:
                        save_one_box(xyxy, imc, file=save_dir / 'crops' / names[c] / f'{p.stem}.jpg', BGR=True)

            # Stream results
            im0 = annotator.result()
            if view_img:
                if platform.system() == 'Linux' and p not in windows:
                    windows.append(p)
                    cv2.namedWindow(str(p), cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)  # allow window resize (Linux)
                    cv2.resizeWindow(str(p), im0.shape[1], im0.shape[0])
                cv2.imshow(str(p), im0)
                cv2.waitKey(1)  # 1 millisecond

            # Save results (image with detections)
            if save_img:
                if dataset.mode == 'image':
                    cv2.imwrite(save_path, im0)
                else:  # 'video' or 'stream'
                    if vid_path[i] != save_path:  # new video
                        vid_path[i] = save_path
                        if isinstance(vid_writer[i], cv2.VideoWriter):
                            vid_writer[i].release()  # release previous video writer
                        if vid_cap:  # video
                            fps = vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
                            w = int(vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
                            h = int(vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
                        else:  # stream
                            fps, w, h = 30, im0.shape[1], im0.shape[0]
                        save_path = str(Path(save_path).with_suffix('.mp4'))  # force *.mp4 suffix on results videos
                        vid_writer[i] = cv2.VideoWriter(save_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (w, h))
                    vid_writer[i].write(im0)

        # Print time (inference-only)
        LOGGER.info(f"{s}{'' if len(det) else '(no detections), '}{dt[1].dt * 1E3:.1f}ms")

    # Print results
    t = tuple(x.t / seen * 1E3 for x in dt)  # speeds per image
    LOGGER.info(f'Speed: %.1fms pre-process, %.1fms inference, %.1fms NMS per image at shape {(1, 3, *imgsz)}' % t)
    if save_txt or save_img:
        s = f"\n{len(list(save_dir.glob('labels/*.txt')))} labels saved to {save_dir / 'labels'}" if save_txt else ''
        LOGGER.info(f"Results saved to {colorstr('bold', save_dir)}{s}")
    if update:
        strip_optimizer(weights[0])  # update model (to fix SourceChangeWarning)


def parse_opt():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--weights', nargs='+', type=str, default=ROOT / 'yolov5s.pt', help='model path or triton URL')
    parser.add_argument('--source', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/images', help='file/dir/URL/glob/screen/0(webcam)')
    parser.add_argument('--data', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml', help='(optional) dataset.yaml path')
    parser.add_argument('--imgsz', '--img', '--img-size', nargs='+', type=int, default=[640], help='inference size h,w')
    parser.add_argument('--conf-thres', type=float, default=0.25, help='confidence threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--iou-thres', type=float, default=0.45, help='NMS IoU threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--max-det', type=int, default=1000, help='maximum detections per image')
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='', help='cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--view-img', action='store_true', help='show results')
    parser.add_argument('--save-txt', action='store_true', help='save results to *.txt')
    parser.add_argument('--save-conf', action='store_true', help='save confidences in --save-txt labels')
    parser.add_argument('--save-crop', action='store_true', help='save cropped prediction boxes')
    parser.add_argument('--nosave', action='store_true', help='do not save images/videos')
    parser.add_argument('--classes', nargs='+', type=int, help='filter by class: --classes 0, or --classes 0 2 3')
    parser.add_argument('--agnostic-nms', action='store_true', help='class-agnostic NMS')
    parser.add_argument('--augment', action='store_true', help='augmented inference')
    parser.add_argument('--visualize', action='store_true', help='visualize features')
    parser.add_argument('--update', action='store_true', help='update all models')
    parser.add_argument('--project', default=ROOT / 'runs/detect', help='save results to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--name', default='exp', help='save results to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--exist-ok', action='store_true', help='existing project/name ok, do not increment')
    parser.add_argument('--line-thickness', default=3, type=int, help='bounding box thickness (pixels)')
    parser.add_argument('--hide-labels', default=False, action='store_true', help='hide labels')
    parser.add_argument('--hide-conf', default=False, action='store_true', help='hide confidences')
    parser.add_argument('--half', action='store_true', help='use FP16 half-precision inference')
    parser.add_argument('--dnn', action='store_true', help='use OpenCV DNN for ONNX inference')
    parser.add_argument('--vid-stride', type=int, default=1, help='video frame-rate stride')
    opt = parser.parse_args()
    opt.imgsz *= 2 if len(opt.imgsz) == 1 else 1  # expand
    print_args(vars(opt))
    return opt


def main(opt):
    check_requirements(exclude=('tensorboard', 'thop'))
    run(**vars(opt))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    opt = parse_opt()
    main(opt)
```

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623233/calculating-the-width-of-the-yolo-bounding-box-in-pixels) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and efforts. No, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: yolo has specific format for bounding box representation, VOC format is more stable for those use cases. See [pybboxes](https://github.com/devrimcavusoglu/pybboxes), you can easily convert from one to another.

Answer (score 3):

You have to first understand how the bounding boxes are encoded by the YOLOv7 framework. There are several ways coordinates could be stored.

First, bounding box coordinates are usually expressed in the image coordinate system. The most common one has its origin in the top-left image corner and the axes (X, Y) are oriented to the right and to the bottom respectively:

```
(0,0)          x
   ┌───────────┬────────────►X
   │           │
   │           │
   │           │
   │           │
 y─┼───────────o
   │
   ▼
   Y
```

A bounding box can be expressed in this system via multiple coordinates:

```
                      width
                   ◄──────────►
          (0,0)   xmin  xmid  xmax
             ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────►X
             │     │     │     │
       ▲ ymin├─────┼─────┴─────┤
       │     │     │           │
height │ ymid├─────┤     ┼     │
       │     │     │    box    │
       ▼ ymax├─────┴───────────┘
             │
             ▼
             Y
```

Where `(xmid, ymid)` is the bounding box center, `(width, height)` its size, `(xmin, ymin)` its top-left corner and and `(xmax, ymax)` its bottom-right corner.

Only four of those are sufficient to describe a bounding box entirely. Two of the most common ones are:

- `(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`
- `(xmid, ymid, width, height)`

You can deduce the others coordinates from those four, for instance:

- `width = xmax - xmin`
- `xmid = (xmin + xmax) / 2`
- `ymax = ymid + width / 2`
- etc...

Additionally, bounding box coordinates can either be expressed in pixels (absolute coordinates) or relative to the image size (a real number in [0, 1]). If the image size is `(img_w, img_h)`, then you can translate from absolute to relative like this:

- `x_rel = x_abs / img_w`
- `y_rel = y_abs / img_h`

and from relative to absolute like this:

- `x_abs = x_rel * img_w`
- `y_abs = y_rel * img_h`

Given all that, you should be able to compute the width and height the bounding boxes easily. You just need to know in which format YOLOv7 coordinates are stored. To my knowledge, YOLOv5 stores them as `(xmid, ymid, width, height)` in relative format.

---

I developed a Python [package](https://github.com/laclouis5/globox) to convert bounding box annotations from/into several widely used formats such as YOLO, COCO and CVAT. If that suits your need, you can install it with:

```
pip install globox
```

and read YOLOv7 annotations like this:

```py
from globox import *
from pathlib import Path

annotations = AnnotationSet.from_yolo_v7(
  folder="/path/to/txt/files/",
  image_folder="/path/to/images/",
)
```

then you have access to the coordinates of every bounding boxes:

```py
for box in annotations.all_boxes:
  print(box.xmin, box.ymin, box.width, box.height)
```

I let you inspect the API for a complete overview of what is possible.